# Uninitialized read error on Asio tcp socket

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, tcp, boost-asio

I have a c++ windows app which works fine. I use `Boost::asio`. When I tried porting on linux, the app did not work as intended at all. After getting discouraged by valgrind errors, I decided to run DrMemory on windows and fix the errors that would show up first. One error I have not been able to fix is an error I have deducted to be about my socket. Is it not possible to use `scoped_ptr` with a socket? Anyways, here are the errors DrMemory records, followed by some relevant code. The code does not compile if I change the logic for the socket from a smart pointer to either references or a bare pointer. (Some error about the socket, I can't recall exactly what it was, but it was the same for reference and pointer)

What have I done wrong with this?

DrMemory : http://pastebin.com/gHQYrCjA

NetworkEntity.cpp

```
#include "boost/asio.hpp"
#include "NetworkEntity.h"
#include "boost/bind.hpp"

NetworkEntity::NetworkEntity(std::string address, std::string port)
  : address_(address), 
    port_(port)
{
}

void NetworkEntity::stop()
{
    if (socket_)
    {
        socket_->close();
    }
    socket_.reset();
    timeout_->cancel();
}

void NetworkEntity::check_timeout(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    if (error != boost::asio::error::operation_aborted)
    {
        stop();

        errorbuf_  << "timed out after " << TIMEOUT_ << " seconds\n";

    }
}

std::vector<std::string> NetworkEntity::tcpPoll(const char* message, const char endOfMessage)
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    try{
        //initialize timeout timer.
        timeout_.reset(new boost::asio::deadline_timer(io_service));
        timeout_->expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(TIMEOUT_));
        timeout_->async_wait(boost::bind(&NetworkEntity::check_timeout, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        //initialize connection, which writes then reads.
        tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
        start_connect(&io_service, resolver.resolve(tcp::resolver::query(address_, port_)), message, endOfMessage);
        //run async operations, wait for their completion.
        io_service.run();

        //retrieve answer
        std::vector<std::string> lines;
        std::string line;
        std::istream is(&answer_);
        int i = 0;
        while (std::getline(is, line)){ 
            lines.push_back(line); 
        }
        //reset answer to nothing (not needed but is a security)
        answer_.consume(answer_.size());
        request_.consume(request_.size());
        setError(errorbuf_.str());
        errorbuf_.str(""); // clear the contents
        errorbuf_.clear();
        return lines;
    }
    catch (std::exception& e){

        errorbuf_ << "An exception has occured : " << e.what() << "\n";

        return std::vector<std::string>{};
    }
}

void NetworkEntity::start_connect(boost::asio::io_service* io_service, tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator, const std::string message, const char endOfMessage)
{
    // Start the asynchronous connect operation.
    socket_.reset(new tcp::socket(*io_service));
    socket_->async_connect(endpoint_iterator->endpoint(),
        boost::bind(&NetworkEntity::handle_connect, this, io_service, boost::asio::placeholders::error, message, endOfMessage));
}

void NetworkEntity::handle_connect(boost::asio::io_service* io_service, const boost::system::error_code& err, const std::string message, const char endOfMessage)
{
    if (err)
    {
        stop();

        errorbuf_ << "Connect error : " << err.message() << "\n";

    }
    else
    {
        start_write(message, endOfMessage);
    }
}

void NetworkEntity::start_write(const std::string message, const char endOfMessage)
{
    //convert message from string to streambuf
    std::ostream request_stream(&request_);
    request_stream << message;
    //end of convertion
    boost::asio::async_write(*socket_, request_,
        boost::bind(&NetworkEntity::handle_write, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, endOfMessage));
}

void NetworkEntity::handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& error, const char endOfMessage)
{
    if (!error)
    {
        boost::asio::io_service io;
        boost::asio::deadline_timer wait(io);
        wait.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(500));
        wait.wait();
        start_read(endOfMessage);
    }
    else
    {
        stop();

        errorbuf_ << "Write error : " << error.message() << "\n";

    }
}

void NetworkEntity::start_read(const char endOfMessage)
{
    boost::asio::async_read_until(*socket_, answer_, endOfMessage,
        boost::bind(&NetworkEntity::handle_read, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}

void NetworkEntity::handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    if (error)
    {

        errorbuf_ << "read error : " << error.message() << "\n";

    }
    stop();
}
```

NetworkEntity.h

```
#inclued "boost/asio.hpp"
#include "boost/array.hpp"
#include "boost/scoped_ptr.hpp"
#include "boost/shared_ptr.hpp"
#include "Error.h"

#ifndef NETWORK_ENTITY_H
#define NETWORK_ENTITY_H

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
class NetworkEntity : private boost::noncopyable
{
public:
    NetworkEntity(std::string address, std::string port);

    std::vector<std::string> tcpPoll(const char* message, const char endOfMessage);

private:
    void stop();
    void check_timeout(const boost::system::error_code&  error);
    void start_write(const std::string message, const char endOfMessage);
    void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& error, const char endOfMessage);
    void start_read(const char endOfMessage);
    void start_connect(boost::asio::io_service* io_service, tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator, const std::string message, const char endOfMessage);
    void handle_connect(boost::asio::io_service* io_service, const boost::system::error_code& error, const std::string message, const char endOfMessage);
    void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& error);
    void timeoutHandler(const boost::system::error_code& error);
    boost::scoped_ptr<tcp::socket> socket_;
    boost::scoped_ptr<boost::asio::deadline_timer> timeout_;
    std::string address_;
    std::string port_;
    boost::asio::streambuf answer_;
    boost::asio::streambuf request_;
    static const int TIMEOUT_ = 5;

    std::stringstream errorbuf_; //loggable by functions I removed for the sake of simplicity
    boost::shared_ptr<Error> error_;
    boost::scoped_ptr<boost::asio::deadline_timer> logTimer_;

    NetworkEntity(const NetworkEntity& e) = delete;
    NetworkEntity & operator=(const NetworkEntity& e) = delete;
};
#endif
```

main.cpp (I did not try to compile this one, sorry if there are any errors)

```
#include "NetworkEntity.h"
#include <iostream>

    int main()
{
    NetworkEntity n("192.168.0.36", "10001");
    while (true){
        std::string mes;
        std::cin >> mes;
        std::vector<std::string> ans = n.tcpPoll(mes.c_str(), '\n'); //message to send, last character expected to recieve (read until)
        for (int i = 0; i < ans.size(); i++)
            std::cout << ans[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: What compiler do you use on linux? Is it the same boost version?

Comment: I use gcc (g++) and yes, it is the same version of boost

Comment: you can use smart pointer with socket (integer file descriptor), but you need to pass it as address and use custom deleter (to use close on it, not delete it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I made it work on linux and run valgrind-clean. My problem wasn't even in what was shown here, it was that I was passing `"10001\r"` instead of `"10001"` as the port, which made the resolver fail. That `\r` came from a `getline` (read from file) which deleted only the `\n` in `"10001\r\n"`

Answer (score 1):

Some tips to help you to find the problem, hopefully:

1. move `boost::asio::io_service io_service` from `NetworkEntity::tcpPoll` to class member variable.
2. I don't undertsand why you create another ioservice in `NetworkEntity::handle_write`, use the member variable.
3. In `NetworkEntity::tcpPoll`, '`timeout_.reset(new boost::asio::deadline_timer(io_service))`' will create a memory leak, use `std::make_shared`
4. I do not understand the error handling in `NetworkEntity::handle_write` as you 'reset' the socket, and continue the io_service.run() in `NetworkEntity::tcpPoll` without even ckecking kind of error.

And last but not least, about your question '**Is it not possible to use scoped_ptr with a socket?**', socket is one thing, pointer, scoped or not another thing. You should read and learn about smart pointer, nothing magic behind that term, only a reference count, and delete when that count reach 0.

And as bonus a free advice: forget DrMemory and understand exactly each line, each statement of your code, if function has a returned value, get it and check it ...

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

```
socket_.reset();
```

should be inside the prior 'if' block.

Comment: `reset()` only resets the smart pointer to nothing, the error is not there (yes, I have tried it)